# Is constant force a useful parameter for correct drilling operation?

Tags: drilling

I'm trying to figure out a correlation between correct feed rating and the feed force.

Can a specific feed force be declared to create the correct feed rate per material per tool speed?

Comment: A constant force means thats you must have a changing speed dv/dt which is not what you want in a drilling process!

Comment: Let's suppose that we could somehow keep the speed constant. Would the constant feed force still be irrelevant to constant feed rate?